# optimization with strict inequality of variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Maximize $f(x_1,x_2, x_3) = x_{2}+x_{3} - (x_{2}^2+x_{3}^2)$ given $\sum_{i=1}^{3}x_{i} = 1$ and $x_{i}>0$ for $i=1,2,3$. I f I assume that $x_{i}\geq0$ for $i=1,2,3$ then the solution is $x_2 = x_3 = 1/2, x_1 = 0$. How to get the solution when we have strict inequlity $x_{i}>0$ for $i=1,2,3$ ?

Comment: To simplify the question slightly, and for you to see the problem, what is the optimal solution of maximize $x$ subject to $x < 1$?

Comment: I did not get it.

Comment: $f$ does not depend on $x_1$. Is that OK?

Comment: I'm asking you to tell me what is the largest $x$ such that $x < 1$. That's an even simpler problem than the one you are trying to solve, and the problem you will have in defining that solution, generalizes to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

By C-S and AM-GM $$x_2+x_3-(x_2^2+x_3^2)=x_2+x_3-\frac{1}{2}(1^2+1^2)(x_2^2+x_3^2)\leq x_2+x_3-\frac{(x_2+x_3)^2}{2}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\cdot(x_2+x_3)(2-x_2-x_3)\leq\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x_2+x_3+2-x_2-x_3}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{2}.$$

The equality occurs for $x_2=x_3$ and when $x_2+x_3=2-x_2-x_3,$

which gives $x_2=x_3=\frac{1}{2}$ and $x_1=0.$

If $x_1>0$ then the maximum does not exist, but $\sup{f}=\frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: Can I actually ask a quick question: How do you become so good with inequalities? I find inequalities difficult, and it seems like *every* inequality question I come across, you have answered it. This may seem like a dumb question, but at the end of the day, I am just a kid. A kid who is very passionate in the fields of mathematics. You actually inspire me... but I don't target for a discussion here, for I know my place when commenting hah

Comment: I just like to prove inequalities.